# SciPy Relative Frequency: Default Real Limits

Tags: python, numpy, statistics, scipy

I have a question about the 'defaultreallimits' parameter in scipy.stats.relfreq() :

the 'defaultreallimits' parameter allows for specifying a tuple as (lower, upper) for the thresholds according to which, the relative frequency of data at a given array can be calculated. However, it is not clear to me whether such tuple of upper and lower thresholds is inclusive of values that are exactly equal to the specified upper and lower limits.
For example, with the following line of code, will the values equal to 100 or 500 in my_array be counted in the calculation of the relative frequency?

scipy.stats.relfreq(my_array, numbins=10, defaultreallimits=(100,500), weights=None)

This is the link to the description of the 'defaultreallimits' on SciPy:
http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.relfreq.html

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/scipy/scipy/v0.16.0/scipy/stats/stats.py), you see a call to scipy.stats.histogram:

```
h, l, b, e = histogram(a, numbins, defaultreallimits, weights=weights)
```

Looking at the source for `histogram` in the same file, the parameter becomes `defaultlimits`, and you find a call to `numpy.histogram`, where it becomes `range`.

In the [source](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/numpy/numpy/v1.9.1/numpy/lib/function_base.py) for `numpy.histogram`, it uses:

```
bins = linspace(mn, mx, bins + 1, endpoint=True)
```

which means that the endpoints `mn` and `mx` are included, if I read the code right.